# VTK 7.1.1: vtkX3DExporter exception

Tags: c++, vtk

I am using vtkX3DExporter to export a string, but there is an exception when I'm calling GetOutputString().

Writing to a file is successful but writing to a string is not.

I am using VS2017 and my building target is an x64 dll . Another exe imports this dll and tests it like this:

```
// ... codes ...

exporter->SetFileName("D:\\TestFolder\\cccccccc.x3d");

exporter->Write(); // Writes to file successfully 

exporter->WriteToOutputStringOn(); // Turns On "WriteToOutputString"

exporter->GetWriteToOutputString(); // Returns 1

exporter->GetOutputStringLength(); // Returns 0

exporter->GetOutputString(); // Exception here.
```

I can't catch this exception (I don't know why. I used try and catch blocks but my exe just crashes) so I don't know the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find the answer. I should call exporter->Update() before trying to get the output string.